# Java Instanceof method Confusion

Tags: java, interface, boolean, instanceof

Suppose we have the following definition.

```
interface Vessel{}
interface Toy{}
class Boat implements Vessel{}
class Speedboat extends Boat implements Toy{}
```

In main, we have these:

```
Boat b = new Speedboat();
```

and `(b instanceof Toy)` evaluates to be `true`? Why? My understanding is that the reference type of `b` is `Boat`, but `Boat` has nothing to do with `Toy`, so it should be `false` but the answer is `true`.

Comment: You should read [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Boat` has nothing to with `Toy`, you are right.

**But** you are not handling a `Boat` here but an actual `SpeedBoat` which is stored in a `Boat` variable. And that `SpeedBoat` is an instance of `Toy`.

The type in which you store the `new Speedboat()` does not matter since Java checks at runtime wether or not the *actual* objects is an *instance of* something else.

That way you can write something like

```
public boolean callSpeedBoatMethodIfPossible(Boat b) {
    if (b instanceof SpeedBoat) {
        ((SpeedBoat)b).driveVerySpeedy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

So it checks a type of an OBJECT but not a type of REFERENCE to the object.

Answer (score 2):

Compile type of `b` is `Boat`. But its run-time type is `Speedboat`.

[What is the difference between a compile time type vs run time type for any object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963943/what-is-the-difference-between-a-compile-time-type-vs-run-time-type-for-any-obje)