# Java code related to equals method

Tags: java, equals

I am practicing for an exam, and found a sample problem that I don't understand.

For the following code, find what the output is:

```
public class Test {

    private static int count = 0;

    public boolean equals(Test testje) {
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Object t1 = new Test();
        Object t2 = new Test();
        Test t3 = new Test();
        Object o1 = new Object();

        ++count; t1.equals(t2);
        ++count; t1.equals(t3);
        ++count; t3.equals(o1);
        ++count; t3.equals(t3);
        ++count; t3.equals(t2);
    }
}
```

The output of this code is `count = 4`, but I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The correct answer to "what does code like this do" should be "gets the too-clever programmer fired."

Comment: I'm not horribly familiar with modern Java, could you point out the cleverness @fluffy ?

Comment: @Daniel see eran's answer - it has vastly different behaviors based on the call-site type of the method parameter, thanks to a purposefully confusing method overload.

Comment: I'll also note that using dutch variable names in code is heavily frowned upon.

Comment: Compile and run to fund out for yourself.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions

Comment: I wish that Java equals exercise! Then I wouldn't need to go to the gym. ;)

Comment: I wish I could 'fund' myself.  But I'm broke :)

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger, would take 10 secs to find out whats going on

Comment: Teachers that come up with cute exam questions like this should be fired.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The first thing you should note is that `public boolean equals(Test testje)` **doesn't** override `Object`'s `equals`, since the argument is `Test` instead of `Object`, so the signatures don't match.

Therefore the `main` method calls `equals(Test testje)` exactly once - when executing `t3.equals(t3);` - since that's the only case in which both the static type of the instance `equals` is executed for and the type of the argument are the `Test` class.

`t3.equals(t3);` is the 4th `equals` statement (which comes after 4 increments of the static `count` variable), so 4 is printed.

All the other `equals` statements execute `Object`'s `equals`, and therefore print nothing.

A more detailed explanation :

`t1.equals()` calls `Object`'s `equals` regardless of the type of the argument, since the static (compile time) type of `t1` is `Object`, and the `Test` class doesn't override that method. The `Object` class doesn't have an `equals` method with a single `Test` argument, so `equals(Test testje)` can't be called, regardless of the dynamic (runtime type) of `t1`.

`t3.equals()` can execute either `Object`'s `equals` or `Test`'s equals, since the compile time type of `t3` is `Test`, and the `Test` class has two `equals` methods (one inherited from the `Object` class and the other defined in the `Test` class).

The method being chosen depends on the compile time type of the argument :
1. When the argument is `Object` (as in `t3.equals(o1);` or `t3.equals(t2);`), `Object`'s `equals` is called and nothing is printed.
2. When the argument is `Test`, as in `t3.equals(t3);`, both versions of `equals` match that argument, but due to the rules of method overloading, the method with the most specific argument - `equals(Test testje)` - is chosen and the `count` variable is printed.

Comment: Geeeez, that's why I use the @Override annotation

Answer (score 11):

The equals method in Test takes an instance of Test.

All the previous attempts have been made with an instance of Object, which take the inherrited method from the Object class:

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
  return this == o;
}
```

Since there is no print in there, it won't print any value.

Your `++count;` will increment the value of count, so the moment when you actually call your

```
public boolean equals(Test testje){...
```

method, that does print that value, the value of count is 4.

Answer (score 7):

`t3.equals(t3)` is the only line which has the right arguments that match the method signature `public boolean equals (Test testje)` so it's the only line in the program which actually calls that print statement. This question is designed to teach you a few things.

- All class implicitly extend Object
- Object.java contains an equals method which takes type Object
- multiple methods with the same name can exist provided they have different arguments - this is known as method overloading
- the method method overload who's signature matches the arguments at runtime is the method that gets invoked.

Essentially the trick here is that Test implicitly extends Object like all java classes do. Object contains an equals method that takes type Object. t1 and t2 are typed such that at run time the arguments never match the method signature of equals that is defined in Test. Instead it's always calling into the equals method in Object.java because either the base type Is Object in which case the only methods you have access to are the ones defined in Object.java or  the derived type is Object in which case

```
public boolean equals(Test testje)
```

Cannot be entered because in that case at runtime the argument is of type Object which is a Superclass of Test, not a subclass. So instead it looks at the equals method in the Test.java's implicitly typed superclass Object.java which also contains an equals method, which just happens to have a method signature of

```
public boolean equals (Object o)
```

which in this case match our arguments at runtime so this equals method is the one that executes.

Notice in the case of `t3.equals(t3)` both the base type and the derived type of t3 are Test.

```
Test t3 = new Test ();
```

this means that at runtime you are calling the equals method in Test.java and the argument you are passing in is actually of type Test so the method signatures match and the code inside Test.java executes. At this point `count == 4`.

Bonus bit of knowledge for you:

```
@Override
```

annotation you may have seen in a few places explicitly instructs the compiler to fail if it does not find method with the exact same signature somewhere in a Superclass. This is useful to know if you definitely **intend** to override a method and you want to be absolutely sure that you really are overriding the method and you haven't accidentally changed the method in either the superclass or subclass but not both and Introduced a runtime error where the wrong implementation of the method is being called causing unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 4):

There's two key things that you should know.

- Overridden methods must have the exact signatures as their superclass have. (in your example this condition doesn't meet.)
- In Java for an object, we have two types: [*compile* type and *runtime* type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963943/what-is-the-difference-between-a-compile-time-type-vs-run-time-type-for-any-obje). In the following example compile type of `myobj` is `Object` but its runtime type is `Car`.

  ```
  public class Car{
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o){
              System.out.println("something");
              return false;
        }
  }
  ```

  `Object myobj = new Car();`

  Also you should note that `myobj.equals(...)` results in printing `something` in the console.

Comment: @Override is not needed, heck it didn't exist at all until 1.5

Comment: @plugwash is right. You don't need @Override. In fact in this case if you add @Override the code will likely stop compiling because there is no `equals` method in the superclass with the same method signature. @Override annotation is to tell the compiler 'there should be something in a superclass with this exact method signature - please complain if there is not as this method is intended to actually override something on purpose'

Comment: Yep that is why you use @Override. So when you intended to override something but screwed up the details the compiler screams at you rather than silently overloading instead.

Comment: @plugwash Thank you for the hint.