# What doess compile time safety and run time safety mean?

Tags: java, runtime, compile-time

According to [this post about Java Enum](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-enums), runtime-safety can achieved by using `==`operator to compare status and prevent `NullPointerException`.

```
if(testPz.getStatus() == Pizza.PizzaStatus.DELIVERED);
```

Also for `compile-time-safety` although logically the comparison was proved false, this issue is avoided by using the `==` operator.

```
if(testPz.getStatus() == TestColor.GREEN);
```

Can you please tell me what `compile-time-safety` and `runtime-safety` are in Java?

If you can please give me a small example.

Comment: Sharing the context in which you encountered that (quoting a book or answer) may prevent this from being closed as too broad or unclear...

Comment: @ernest_k done.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963943/what-is-the-difference-between-a-compile-time-type-vs-run-time-type-for-any-obje

Comment: @nullpointer thank you for the link. So is this means we can achieve compile time safety only through assigning right data type to the reference? What about the example I have given? Is that wrong? Could you please be more detailed about this?

Comment: @nullpointer at-least please give me a link to detailed post regarding this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, compile-time safety means that your code *follows the rules* of the language, while runtime safety means that your code *does the right thing*. Different languages provide different sets of rules and thus different safety guarantees.

Compile-time safety means that the compiler can analyze your code and guarantee that certain kinds of errors are not present. In Java, a common example is type safety (it is guaranteed that an object in a variable of type `List` is some kind of list implementation). Some languages, such as Kotlin on the JVM, can also guarantee that null-pointer exceptions can't occur because nullable and not-null variables are identified, and explicit checks are required.

Compile-time safety has its limits, however; for example, you can use a *cast* in Java to specifically tell the compiler that "I know the object here is of a certain type, even though you can't prove it", and if you're wrong, you can get a `ClassCastException` when you run the program.

The article you linked to is talking about my second example, null safety. In Java, a variable of a reference type can have the value `null`, which doesn't actually refer to a real instance, and if you try to call a method on that variable, you get a `NullPointerException`. In this example, if you have an enum `Status`, then if you call `statusVariable.equals(VALUE)`, then you'll get an exception if `statusVariable` is null: The expression is compile-time safe, but not runtime-safe, because Java doesn't make guarantees about null values. In contrast, `==` is safe to use with null values, so even if your variable is null, you will get result of `false` instead of an exception.