# Java Composite Pattern: Why can I not add a group to itself?

Tags: java, composite

A `Group` implements the `Figure` interface and in addition declares a public `addFigure` method. Why can I not call the `addFigure` method on my `g1` group object?

```java
public interface Figure  {
    void draw();
}
```

```java
public class Group implements Figure {
    private List<Figure> figures;

    public Group(Figure... figures) {
        this.figures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Figure f : figures) {
            this.figures.add(f);
        }
    }

    public void addFigure(Figure f) {
        this.figures.add(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        for (Figure f : figures) {
            f.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Figure r1 = new Rectangle();
        Figure r2 = new Rectangle();
        Figure r3 = new Rectangle();

        Figure g1 = new Group(r1, r2);
        Figure g2 = new Group(r2, r3);

        g1. // <- only `draw()` availabe, no `addFigure(Figure)`
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's type `Figure`. Cast it to `Group` and you will be able to call `addFigure`

Comment: Because `g1` is a `Figure` but you defined `addFigure` in `Group`

Comment: @adnan_e I would highly discourage casting. If another type with `addFigure(...)` is added, a second condition is needed. With a third, a third one is needed,... This leads to rigid code.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code

Comment: @Turing85 then what would you do instead?

Comment: Btw, there's a `NullPointerException` in your code. Your `figures` field is never initialized, but accessed. I think your IDE is already showing you this with the yellow highlight in line 10.

Comment: @TMOTTM depends on the actual use-case. In the minimal example you gave, I would suggest defining `Group g1 = new Group(r1, r2);` instead of `Figure g1 = new Group(r1, r2);`.

Comment: @knittl Edited the code to make a list.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you're defining a `Figure` type when instanciating the `Group` instance.

Your `Figure` interface defines a `draw` method, but no `addFigure` method.  That method is defined in an implementation of the `Figure` interface.

When you create an instance by the interface, you're bound to the methods defined in that interface, even if the actual instance is of an implementing Type.  As a result, you need to cast the instance to a `Group`, and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `g1` is of static type `Figure`. The compiler has no way of knowing which implementation of the interface is used. When defining the variable, use the type that you need, e.g. `Group g1 = new Group(...)`. Then you will be able to call `addFigure` on your instance:

```
Figure r1 = new Rectangle();
Figure r2 = new Rectangle();
Figure r3 = new Rectangle();

Group g1 = new Group(r1, r2);
Group g2 = new Group(r2, r3);

g1.addFigure(r3);
```

You can use a `Group` anywhere where you would use a `Figure` (think downcasting), but not the other way round (upcasting)

Comment: Does the compiler not see what kind of type I'm providing to the `new` operator? I mean, does the compiler not check the dynamic type (i.e. `new Rectangle()`)?

Comment: It does, but you tell it that the variable `g1` is of type `Figure`, not of type `Group`. That information is "lost" (look up compile time vs run time types, or sometimes static vs dynamic types, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963943/what-is-the-difference-between-a-compile-time-type-vs-run-time-type-for-any-obje). It cannot look up the dynamic type, because the dynamic is inherently a runtime-thing and not known at compile time (again: you tell the compiler that the type is `Figure`, not `Group`)